# URL issue in XAMPP Windows

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am facing a problem with a project recently. The site is running locally fine. Like if I browse the site its showing me the page also if I do some thing like "localsite.dev/students" it is also showing the page. But if I type "localsite.dev/students:auth", I am getting "Access forbidden!". I am using XAMPP in Windows 8. Here is my configuration:

Apache Version  Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1t PHP/5.6.24

PHP Version 5.6.24

Is it a problem with the .htaccess file or any Apache settings problem. Please let me know. The .htaccess file that I am using is like following:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Please help me. I have already spent a lot of time with it. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Apache runs as the "**nobody**" user by default, it might have permission to browse your [OSX/Win] user directory or some of its subdirectories.So, you will receive "**access forbidden**" error when you try and view your development site. Another scenario will be that you might find that you are able to view your dev site, but PHP throws errors when you attempt to write files or make directories on the filesystem.

So, to fix this you can configure Apache to run as your [OSX/Win] user. Open **httpd.conf** and look for following lines:

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User nobody
Group nogroup
```

**Change this to:**

```
User Username01
```

Restart Apache and you are now good to go to navigate your site without any issues, including manipulating files and folders using PHP.

Refer the link for reference: 
[Virtual Hosts in xampp](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/)

Hope It helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This "localsite.dev/students:auth" is not working and I am getting "Access forbidden!" error. Any idea how can I solve it. It seems like URL with colon (:) is not working. How can I solve it in Apache, XAMPP?

Comment: have you tried any URL on the same server which is not having any Colon? I still believe that URL is the issue. But I have never came across such scenario. Still lets try to look into it. By the way , Please accept my answer if it helps you

Comment: Yes the other URL is working fine. As I stated in my original question, only the URL with the colon sign is not working. URL like "localsite.dev/students" is working fine but URL like "localsite.dev/students:auth" is not working.

Comment: I have to try that.. Probably I will get back to you once I will try with this scenario.

Comment: But I think whatever I have answered helped you in the understanding. Ofcourse I will look into the issue if I am able to replicate the same. Accept the answer if at all its helpful.